# Error handle a missing key in SQL mapping

Tags: sql, mapping, presto

I am new to Presto SQL and I am trying to map items but receiving a 'Key not present in map:formId' error. I was wondering how to handle mapping when one of the keys is missing? When I remove that particular key, the query runs just fine. But in the future, this key may have data and so removing it does not help in the long run. I have seen suggestions to use element_at but I am not sure how to implement that. Additionally, I have tried COALESCE(TRY() but it will only take one argument and not an array.

What I currently have:

```sql
with list as(
select t.week,t.event,t.team,t.continent,t.country
from table as t 
where t.date >= '2022-02-10'
and t.team_name IN ('charlie','Anna') 
and COALESCE(
               t.info['formId'], 
               t.info['roomId'],
               t.info['hall_name'],
               t.info['teAM_id'])  IN ('catalog 0', 'catalog 1', 'catalog 2', 'catalog 3', 'catalog 4')
)
select * from list
```

The error I am receiving is 'Key not present in map:formId'

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Presto documentation for [Map Functions and Operators](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html), it looks as if you should be able to replace `t.info['formId']` with `element_at(t.info, 'formId')` to get the value if it exists and NULL if it doesn't, which [`COALESCE`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#coalesce) will then ignore and move onto the next item (`t.info['roomId']`). You might need to do that for all four `t.info['key']` items — you know your data better than I do.

Slide 55 of [Presto Training - Advanced SQL Features in Presto](https://www.starburst.io/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Presto-Training-Series-Advanced-SQL-Features-in-Presto.pdf) supports my hypothesis.